# C# - Use WebImage.GetImageFromRequest() with multiple uploads

Tags: c#, razor, file-upload, webmatrix

I am trying to upload multiple images from a form. And then grab the images using WebImage.GetImageFromRequest(). This works fine with a single upload field, but I'm not sure how to use this to get multiple files.

My HTML form:

```
<input id="uploadBtn1" type="file" name="Image1" accept=".jpg,.png" class="upload"/>
<input id="uploadBtn2" type="file" name="Image2" accept=".jpg,.png" class="upload"/>
<input id="uploadBtn3" type="file" name="Image3" accept=".jpg,.png" class="upload"/>
```

My C# Code

```
if (IsPost)
{
 photo1 = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest("image1");
 newFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + Path.GetFileName(photo1.FileName);
 imagePath = @"branding\" + newFileName;
 photo1.Save(@"~\" + imagePath);

 photo2 = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest("image2");
 newFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + Path.GetFileName(photo2.FileName);
 imagePath = @"branding\" + newFileName;
 photo2.Save(@"~\" + imagePath);

 photo3 = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest("image3");
 newFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + Path.GetFileName(photo3.FileName);
 imagePath = @"branding\" + newFileName;
 photo3.Save(@"~\" + imagePath);
}
```

This throws an error:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Line 101:     newFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + Path.GetFileName(photo3.FileName);

I think that I'm using the incorrect syntax for: photo1 = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest("image1");

How do I specify this to get the the "image1" upload field? And "image2", "image3" etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you include

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

into your form?

Example:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Here is an example how to iterate through multiple files:

```
https://forums.asp.net/t/2024891.aspx?WebImage+helper+multiple+image+upload
```

Comment: That link was the answer. Just needed to specify the field name: 
 photo1 = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest("Image1");